# Wired mouse and keyboard not working with USB 3.0 Hub

Tags: drivers, usb

I am trying to use a wired mouse and wired keyboard with my 13" Dell XPS running Ubuntu (kernel @ Linux 5.19.0-38-generic), which has only two USB-C ports, via a [USB docking station](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B085ZYKX7K/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

The wired mouse and keyboard are not working with USB hub when connecting to my Ubuntu device. The same setup works in the same hardware if using Windows instead.

More than one wired mouse was tested (they all work in a different computer). Wireless mouses with USB adapters are also not working.

My hub recognizes the DP connection for the external display, and also recognizes external HDs, but does not recognize smaller flashdrives.

When testing the same wired components on an HP Zbook running the same Ubuntu version, via regular USB port (not through the hub), all devices work.

The hub powers whatever wired mouses I connect there.

```
# with the USB Hub, with a DP monitor, wired mouse and wired keyboard connected to hub
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5517 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:532d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
# The two lines below are the diff when connecting the hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub


# without the USB Hub
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5517 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:532d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


sudo dmesg -Hw
........
# disconnecting the device
[abr18 12:19] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  +0,000007] usb 2-3.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  +0,001302] r8152 2-3.3:1.0 enx34298f73ac4b: Stop submitting intr, status -108

# reconnecting the device
[ +13,142854] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,048035] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice=90.14
[  +0,000017] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000003] usb 2-3: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
[  +0,000003] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  +0,000003] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 000000000
[  +0,002106] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000539] hub 2-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +2,217332] usb 2-3.3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,020410] usb 2-3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=30.00
[  +0,000011] usb 2-3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  +0,000004] usb 2-3.3: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[  +0,000002] usb 2-3.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  +0,000003] usb 2-3.3: SerialNumber: 000001
[  +0,083779] usb 2-3.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,046035] r8152 2-3.3:1.0: load rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 successfully
[  +0,026758] r8152 2-3.3:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
[  +0,056425] r8152 2-3.3:1.0 enx34298f73ac4b: renamed from eth0

xinput list 
# Shows no diff when using or not using the USB hub with wired mouse and keyboard
```

If I try `sudo dmesg -Hw` with the hub connected and later plug in the mouse or keyboard, nothing shows up.

Commenting out any `usb` lines within the only file at `mambaforge/lib/udev/rules.d`, which was `90-pulseaudio.rules`, according to a [similar topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52264/keyboard-mouse-do-not-work-when-connected-to-usb-hub-but-only-on-fedora-works).

Furthermore, I have also made a probe on the PC usikng, with which I couldn't really get anywhere, but can provide here if it's any help.

There seems to be a [related bug described here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213839), but...
when I have navigated to my own `/lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb`, the **only** file here is `ledtrig-usbport.ko`, instead of the multitude of files shown in any of the related releases (e.g., https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v5.19/drivers/usb/core).
Wonder if this is somehow pointing to missing files on my end, even after having a clean Ubuntu install and `sudo apt-get update` frequently.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu that kernel could be on a number of different versions.

Comment: My bad - it's a fresh Ubuntu install with the latest Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: And what kernel?

Comment: This might sound like a stupid suggestion but did you try flipping the USB-C connection over to see if that resolves the issue?  One guess I have is that the internal MUX that directs the USB-C signals about is not working as it should.  By flipping the connector over that moves which wires are carrying the USB 3.x and DisplayPort signals.  By working with Windows and not Ubuntu my guess is the dock is simply poorly designed and is in violation of the published specification, and there's not likely a driver fix for that.

Comment: @David I did include the kernel on the post, just not the Ubuntu version! Kernel is Linux 5.19.0-38-generic which is not as recent as could be, but would require a manual kernel update.

Comment: @MacGuffin no such thing as a stupid suggestion. I just tried doing that and trying 4x on both ports, and the issue still persists. Hmmm I understand your argument, but seeing other places such as [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213839) I am nearly convinced there is a small issue. My laptop not having the proper files on `/kernel/drivers/usb/core` might be part of the issue? And I don't know how to properly setup these files there, which seem to be part of the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an extension cable (USB-C to USB-C) which was the culprit. It worked fine in Windows, but apparently made part of the hub (the USB-B ports) incompatible in Linux.